# Ubuntu 15.10 not waking up after second suspend

Tags: suspend, 15.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, I face an issue with the `suspend` feature.

The reproduction workflow is the following :

1. Boot the system and open a session
2. Suspend
3. Wake up <- At this point, everything is going well
4. Suspend again
5. Wake up <- This is where I get a blank screen

I have tried the following :

- Disable Wifi before suspending
- Spamming the Escape or Space key while waking up
- Increasing the brightness of the screen after waking up
- Switching between `Ctrl+Alt+F2`/`Ctrl+Alt+F7`
- Blindly typing my password

None of those actions work in my case.

My question is : does someone have an idea of what is going on, and do you know if there is a log file or something that could help me to figure out what fails ?

Comment: there might be some information in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, but look everywhere in `/var/log`

Comment: `pm-suspend.log` is empty. I also checked `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, `kern.log` and `Xorg.0.log`, but nothing caught my eye.

Comment: Because 15.10 uses systemd I will make a "journal" folder in /var/log/ to enable history journal, after a system restart you will be able to see older logs (not only actual boot), than you can try analyse your log with journalctl -b xxxxxx. Where xxxxxx is a boot session to choose

Comment: I think this should go to the bugtracker. I face the same issue on an upgrade of Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. A clean install of 15.10 works fine without issues.

Comment: @EdiD: This directory remains empty. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @dounny: try this : sudo nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf and under the [Journal] section, uncomment the Storage=auto and change "auto" to "persistent" to enable persistent logging